# "Invalid application of 'sizeof' to interface 'Fraction' in non-fragile ABI" in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, sizeof

I'm studying Steven Kochan's "Programming in Objective-C 2.0". We created a Fraction object with two int instance variables. Later in the book Kochan uses the sizeof statement on a Fraction object's pointer myFract:

```
sizeof(*myFract)
```

When I do this, I receive a compile error:

> Invalid application of 'sizeof' to interface 'Fraction' in non-fragile ABI

http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#sizeof-interface states this error could occur for an object who's size can change but a Fraction instance only contains the two int instance variables (plus an "inherited isa member" mentioned in the book).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object's size could still change because you're using the modern ABI. In older versions of Objective-C, objects were basically structs and that meant it was possible to sizeof() them. This is no longer the case, and it was never a particularly good idea in the first place. I'm not sure what Kochan was trying to teach with it, but FYI this is not necessary to program Objective-C. You should be able to get the old behavior by building as 32-bit on the Mac, but again, that isn't something you'll want to do in real programs.

Comment: Kochan's book identifies the underlying objective-c objects as structs and wikipedia'd the objective c language and saw that version 2.0 was the latest, so I thought I was update. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @afable: The Objective-C 2.0 distinction was basically because the language had stagnated for years and that was when Apple started moving it again. The language has changed quite a bit since the introduction of 2.0. And the fragile-vs-nonfragile thing is actually an ABI issue — the 32-bit Mac version uses the fragile legacy runtime, while the 64-bit and iPhone versions use the modern runtime.

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on what Chuck said, you should use `class_getInstanceSize()` at runtime if you really need to know the size of an object.

Comment: After finding that I had to import objc/runtime.h I was able to use this. Thank you.

Comment: I should have mentioned that. Sorry!