# How do I fix these 15 errors in Xcode? ...Semantic issues and no matching constructor for initialization?

Tags: xcode, archive, viewcontroller, openfeint, subscript

Totally stumped here, need help please...

1. Open Xcode
2. Project > Archive
3. Build Failed with 15 errors
4. ViewController.mm error: No matching constructor for initialization of 'OFDelegate'
5. LinkedList.m error: Subscript requires size of interface node which is not constant in non-fragile ABI

This would build successfully in previous versions of Xcode

I expect to see build successful and instead I see failed build with 15 errors

I am using Xcode v4.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.2 Lion.

Build errors:
Screenshot #1:  http://cl.ly/CYo2/o
Screenshot #2:  http://cl.ly/CY60/o

Answer (score 0):

This error (the ABI message) comes up sometimes when trying to build against code originally compiled for the old runtime. The modern runtime (the 'non-fragile ABI') now available is a lot more stable but prevents certain memory-based tricks which depend on how the compiler lays out instance variables. You use one of those tricks in your linked list - calling `sizeof(Node)`.

Basically, you can't call `sizeof(ivar)` anymore. See here: ["Invalid application of 'sizeof' to interface 'Fraction' in non-fragile ABI" in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219319/invalid-application-of-sizeof-to-interface-fraction-in-non-fragile-abi-in). You'll need to re-write that linked list class if you're building for iOS, or revert to the old, fragile runtime if you're on 32 bit OS X.

Comment: I don't have the know-how to re-write a class.  How do I revert to the old, fragile runtime?  I want to solve this in the most trivial manner possible.  Thank you. -Steven.